# Argument of type 'Notifications' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Notifications[] | Record<EntityId, Notifications>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I am facing this issue when creating an Async Thunk using Redux Toolkit and using said Thunk as an extraReducer.

When I specify the `Return argument`, `Thunk Argument` and the `ThunkApiConfig` like so it throws the error from the question title at the line `notificationsAdapter.upsertMany()`:

```
export const fetchNotifications = createAsyncThunk<
  Notifications,
  void,
  { state: RootState }
>("notifications/fetchNotifications", async (_, { getState }) => {
  const allNotifications = selectAllNotifications(getState());
  const [latestNotification] = allNotifications;
  const latestTimestamp = latestNotification ? latestNotification.date : "";
  const response = await client.get(
    `/fakeApi/notifications?since=${latestTimestamp}`
  );
  return response.notifications;
});

const notificationsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "notifications",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    allNotificationsRead(state) {
      Object.values(state.entities).forEach((notification) => {
        notification && (notification.read = true);
      });
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(fetchNotifications.pending, (state) => {
      state.status = "loading";
    });
    builder.addCase(fetchNotifications.rejected, (state, action) => {
      state.status = "failed";
      state.error = action.error.message as Error;
    });
    builder.addCase(fetchNotifications.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.status = "succeeded";
      Object.values(state.entities).forEach((notification) => {
        notification && (notification.isNew = !notification.read);
      });
      notificationsAdapter.upsertMany(state, action.payload);
    });
  },
});
```

But when I remove the types from `createAsyncThunk` and assert that `getState()` is the `RootState`(which comes from the store using `export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>` there is no error anymore so I am not sure what is wrong with the values I have previously set.

```
export const fetchNotifications = createAsyncThunk(
  "notifications/fetchNotifications",
  async (_, { getState }) => {
    const allNotifications = selectAllNotifications(getState() as RootState);
    const [latestNotification] = allNotifications;
    const latestTimestamp = latestNotification ? latestNotification.date : "";
    const response = await client.get(
      `/fakeApi/notifications?since=${latestTimestamp}`
    );
    return response.notifications;
  }
);
```

Code for this can be found [here](https://github.com/yudhiesh/Redux-Typescript-Sample/blob/master/src/features/notifications/notificationsSlice.ts).

Comment: I think your return type should be `Notifications[]` as you return an array of objects, not just one entry (and maybe `Notification` would be a better name for an interface describing one item!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got to be very careful with `as` assertions because you will create problems if you assert something that turns out to be incorrect.  For example, your type `Error` is `string | null` but `action.error.message` is `string | undefined`.  What happens when it's `undefined`?

Instead of insisting to Typescript that you have the right type:

```
state.error = action.error.message as Error;
```

You should actually enforce that you do have the right type by using nullish coalescing to replace `undefined` with `null`:

```
state.error = action.error.message ?? null;
```

---

@Nadia's comment is correct.  `upsertMany` expects either an array `Notifications[]` or a keyed object `Record<EntityId, Notifications>`.  Your `fetchNotifications` action is returning a single notification `Notifications`.  Your `client.get` response is `any` so you aren't getting any error from returning the wrong type.

When you remove the types you don't get any error because now your `fetchNotifications` action returns `any`.

You want to make sure that you are returning an array `Notifications[]`.

---

In my opinion the best way to avoid errors like this is to have a strongly-typed `client` that can return the correct type based on the endpoint.

```
interface EndpointMap {
  "/fakeApi/notifications": Notifications;
}

interface Client {
  getOne<K extends keyof EndpointMap>(
    endpoint: K,
    id: string
  ): Promise<EndpointMap[K]>;

  getMany<K extends keyof EndpointMap>(
    endpoint: K,
    args: Record<string, any>
  ): Promise<EndpointMap[K][]>;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed explanation!